# Mobile Disable Scrolling after iframe reaches End

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, scroll

Hey there im trying to stop scrolling when the ifram ends.
The i frame is scrollable but when it reches the end it will scroll the html and i want to disable that i tried.

```
  $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

but this only disables html scrolling but not if the iframe ends.
Thanks in advance.